# Javascript contains statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying check a field in a database to see if it does not contain either "UK_CONTACTS or a blank. If it is either of these conditions I want to copy the that field to another field. I am very very new at this and have come up with the following and have written in text "does not contain" as I don't know the correct syntax for javascript.

```
function getdbasename(){
var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
}

If (dbasedata does not contain "UK_CONTACTS" || dbasedata does not contain " ") {
    _area.value = _dbase_name.value;
}
```

Probably miles out but it's my best shot.

Comment: Where are you running this JavaScript (client-side in the web browser, or server-side) and what database and database library are you using? Are you wanting the client computer to contact your server as the client interacts with the page and fetch new information?

Comment: ouch, but then why not checking the javascript faq? I mean, just typing the same question in the google search bar would provide you tons of results including from reference web sites! I'm saying this gently :-) This would be the best for everyone to do so

Comment: JS is client side, it doesn't connect to your DB, for that you are going to need a server side langague (PHP,ASP.NET, Coldfusion, etc).  Now, you can get JS to call your server side pages with AJAX to get the data when needed, but I think that is adding way to much complexity for you.

Comment: @Limey Well, unless this is JS running on the server, or connecting to a browser-based client-side database. What you describe is certainly the most common scenario, but not (by far) the only one these days.

Comment: @Phrogz: True, but newbies usually are not playing with those kind of things. Plus, comments are small places; I didn't want to drown him in info (I was close enough already ;)

Comment: Just to let you know that the database I'm working on has a web based front end and the javascript is in the html page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `indexOf()`. If `dbasedata.indexOf(someString)` is anything but -1, it contains `someString`.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, I did research it quite a bit but because I am very unfamiliar with programming I couldn't quite make sense of it. Your example has made it a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the indexOf('what you need to check for') function on the string you want to check.

E.g. (field.value.indexOf('myvalue') > 0) will be true if field.value contains the term 'myvalue'